# Are we missing correlation to achieve a artificial intelligence comparable to humans?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, artificial-consciousness, intelligence, correlation

I don't think neural networks are enough to copy human intelligence because in the end a machine only using a neural network to decide on something still is unable to recognize patterns.

So I was wondering how do machines recognize patterns? With correlation! So what if we have two paths:

1. Path of a simple neural network
2. A path of just correlation.

And in the end which output will be given as the result is decided by the same neural network which output a value?

[image]

Comment: I really struggle to follow what you're saying...

Comment: Suppose we have a neural network modelled as a block(A).And a correlation function as a block(B).We give the input to both of these blocks and we get 2 outputs right?Now that we have 2 outputs we let A decide on which output from A or B we will output.

Comment: Please, share possible usage(s) of your suggested Two Path method. It would help us understand better.

Comment: @Cloud Cho should I post a diagram?I dont know how I came up with it tbh I like neural networks and neuroscience as a hobby but still havent been tought it at my university and I was studying about correlation in telecommunications for a exam and I dont know.

Comment: It sounds like that the concept of Correlation in signal brought your question. Diagram, theory, real life problem, possible problem in the future, and etc. Any possible usage, which you think, would help us.

Comment: I was just trying to understand how my brain works and can a):recognize patterns and b):learn through experience.I realized that neural networks cannot give the same pattern recognition with the capabilities of a human so I first thought :lets just add correlation which is pattern recognition essentially and see where it gets me.I realized that these processes must work in parallel but if you simply run 2 algorithms  at the same time with the same input and then choose 1 of the 2 outputs based on another algorith which doesnt change ,....

Comment: ......then 1 will always prevail over the another and there wont be any room for "evolution".And we humans can understand when to discard a pattern (from correction by others) and when to apply its logic to solve a problem (from rewarding).

Comment: It is not clear what your question is. If you want someone to critique your idea or reference similar research, then right now the idea - or perhaps the presentation in the question - seems very vague and incomplete. Potentitally there are related topics - e.g. "Neurons that fire together, wire together" is a well known principle from neurobiology and there are ANNs that use that idea for training - https://neurosciencenews.com/wire-fire-neurons-19835/ - however that is only one way that some kind of self-correlation can occur, and doesn't seem to match your diagram

Comment: @NeilSlater It is a network with feedback.I am asking if this has been tried and if it is a effective way to copy the functions of a human brain.

Comment: Please make your request that you are looking for whether the idea has been tried in the question title. That would help a little, but not enough yet. Th eissue is that there are plenty of neural network architectures and training regimes using feedback. It is far from clear from your question and diagram what kind of feedback you are asking about and how it would relate to the neural network. You may be better off sitting on the idea for a while and waiting until you know more about the subject, so that you can refine the question to be something other people can understand

Comment: @NeilSlater well obviously the backpropagation function IS feedback but this is feedback coming from the 2nd path of the evaluation of the final value.

Comment: The main problem for me (and I suspect most readers) is that I have no idea what you are trying to say with statements like "the 2nd path of the evaluation of the final value". There *might* be something worth answering in that, but you are using vague statements that are not standard for neural networks or AI, and it is not possible to understand what you are saying. Are you able to express your idea mathematically, e.g. to describe the process that occurs during training in your model?